# Handling socketTimeOutException using Call.enqueue on Android Studio(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, socket-timeout-exception

My understanding of `Call.Enqueue` is that the `OnFailure` method is supposed to handle all failed responses including `OnSocketTimeOutException`, however that doesn't seem to be the case for me.

The code below helps to call data from the `NewsApi` services as well as adding an `interceptor` to track requests/response status. I added `.connectTimeout(10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` to test how my app will react in an event of a `OnSocketTimeOutException`

```
object RetrofitHelper {

private const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/"

private fun httpclient(): OkHttpClient {
    val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

    builder.addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)



        builder.addInterceptor(
            ChuckerInterceptor.Builder(application_class.context)
                .collector(ChuckerCollector(application_class.context))
                .maxContentLength(250000L)
                .redactHeaders(emptySet())
                .alwaysReadResponseBody(false)
                .build()
        )
    })
    return builder.build()
}

fun getInstance(): Retrofit {

    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(httpclient())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

object NewsApiCall {
    val api by lazy {
        RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(NewsApi::class.java)
    }
}
}
```

The code below belongs to my `Repository` where the logic of determining whether a `response` is a `success`, `error` or `failure`. The api key provided below is not the real API key, I edited it. I suspect that the error has something to do with the `OnFailure` method.

```
    fun getNewsCall(country: String, Category: String?): MutableLiveData<MutableList<Article>> {
    val call = RetrofitHelper.NewsApiCall.api.getNews(
        country,
        Category,
        "0169333ed3074dccbacd369ae6a3c4"
    )
    var Newlist = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Article>>()

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<NewsDataFromJson> {

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<NewsDataFromJson>,
            response: Response<NewsDataFromJson>
        ) {

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val body = response.body()
                if (body != null) {
                    Newlist.value = body.articles
                }
            } else {
                val jsonObj: JSONObject?
                    jsonObj = response.errorBody()?.string().let { JSONObject(it) }
                    if (jsonObj != null) {
                        MainActivity.apiRequestError = true
                        MainActivity.errorMessage = jsonObj.getString("message")
                        Newlist.value = mutableListOf<Article>()//
                    }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsDataFromJson>, t: Throwable) {
            MainActivity.apiRequestError = true
            MainActivity.errorMessage = t.localizedMessage as String
            Log.d("err_msg", "msg" + t.localizedMessage)
        }

    })
    return Newlist
}
```

The final part is the `MainActivity`, this is where I display the responses, if it is a `success` It will show the news articles, if it is an `error` or a `failure`, an error message is supposed to show up

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        requestNews(GENERAL, generalNews, "us")
        requestNews(TECHNOLOGY, TechNews, "us")
        requestNews(HEALTH, healthNews, "us")
        requestNews(SPORTS, SportsNews, "us")
        requestNews(ENTERTAINMENT, EntertainmentNews, "us")
        requestNews(SCIENCE, ScienceNews, "us")
        requestNews(BUSINESS, BusinessNews, "us")
    }

}
suspend private fun requestNews(newsCategory: String, newsData: MutableList<Article>,country:String) {
    viewModel.getNews(category = newsCategory, Country = country)?.observe(this) {
        newsData.addAll(it)
        totalRequestCount += 1

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {


    if (ScienceNews.isNotEmpty() && BusinessNews.isNotEmpty() && EntertainmentNews.isNotEmpty() && generalNews.isNotEmpty() && healthNews.isNotEmpty() && SportsNews.isNotEmpty() && TechNews.isNotEmpty()) {
        if (apiRequestError == false) {
            ProgresBar.visibility = View.GONE
            FragmentContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        } else if (apiRequestError == true) {
            ProgresBar.visibility = View.GONE
            FragmentContainer.visibility = View.GONE
            val showError: TextView = findViewById(R.id.display_error)
            showError.text = errorMessage
            showError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

    } else if (apiRequestError == true) {
        ProgresBar.visibility = View.GONE
        FragmentContainer.visibility = View.GONE
        val showError: TextView = findViewById(R.id.display_error)
        showError.text = errorMessage
        showError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

        }
    }
}
companion object{
    //var generalNews changed from ArrayList<NewsModel>
    var ScienceNews: MutableList<Article> = mutableListOf()
    var EntertainmentNews: MutableList<Article> = mutableListOf()
    var SportsNews: MutableList<Article> = mutableListOf()
    var BusinessNews: MutableList<Article> = mutableListOf()
    var healthNews: MutableList<Article> = mutableListOf()
    var generalNews: MutableList<Article> = mutableListOf()
    var TechNews: MutableList<Article> = mutableListOf()
    var apiRequestError = false
    var errorMessage = "error"

}

}
```

When I run the app this is what I see, the loading screen is not disappearing which is weird, which leads me to believe that the error may lie with the `OnFailure` method in the Repository.

[image: Error Image]

[image: Error Response]